# Detecting a web socket connection drop

Tags: c#, websocket, windows-8, winjs

In my Windows 8 JS application, I have a web socket object defined like this:

```
var webSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.MessageWebSocket();
webSocket.control.messageType = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketMessageType.utf8;
webSocket.onmessagereceived = that._onMessageReceived;
webSocket.onclosed = that._onClosed;
```

I connect using `webSocket.connectAsync(uri).done(/* ... */)` and that part works fine.

If I stop my web server on the other end, my application doesn't get notified and thinks the connection is still alive. The 'closed' event never fires, and there doesn't seem to be any 'Error' event.

Is there a way to monitor the connection status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The messagereceived event actually fires when the connection fails. Inside the handler, you can use a try catch block around the data reader operation.

```
try {
    var dataReader = args.getDataReader();
    var msg = dataReader.readString(dataReader.unconsumedBufferLength);
} catch (ex) {
    var error = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.getStatus(ex.number);
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a specific Windows 8 question? I've tested the following to work on Windows 7, OSX and Ubuntu (using reasonably new versions of Firefox, Safari and Chrome):

```js
var s = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.hostname+":9876");

s.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("opened socket for unidrive log");
}
s.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("closed");
}
s.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("got message: " + e.data);
}
```

The onclose event fires immediately if the web-server isn't running to start with, or fires on killing the server.

Comment: Yes actually, this is in the context of a Windows 8 application. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this Information - really weird why the socket don't raise the closed-event, but it works great.

One more info for C# developers: to determine the correct exception-errorstatus you have to do call the **WebSocketError**.GetStatus(hresult) instead of the **SocketError**.GetStatus(hresult) method.

```
try
{
    using (DataReader reader = e.GetDataReader())
    {
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        string rawMessage = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

        // Do something with the message...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var errorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.WebSocketError.GetStatus(ex.HResult);
    if (errorStatus == WebErrorStatus.ConnectionAborted)
    {
        // Handle the connection-abort...
    }
}
```